# How to add severity, facility field to Kibana with fluentd parse?

Tags: parsing, logging, devops, kibana, fluentd

I use rsyslog with the default config, traditional template. Rsyslog sends all syslog to fluentd.

My fluentd config:

```
<source>
 @type syslog
 port 5140
 tag rsyslog
</source>

<match rsyslog.*.*>
 @type elasticsearch
 host localhost
 port 9200
 logstash_format true
</match>
```

Kibana:

[image]

How to add severity and facility fields to Kibana?

Comment: Take a look at [record_transformer](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer) plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure `severity_key` (https://docs.fluentd.org/input/syslog#severity_key) and `facility_key` (https://docs.fluentd.org/input/syslog#facility_key) config to extract severity and facility.
So something like this should work:

```
<source>
 @type syslog
 port 5140
 tag rsyslog
 severity_key severity
 facility_key facility
</source>
```